# How to pronounce JOHN?

Tags: pronunciation

Can someone help me to pronounce JOHN correctly? People seemed to struggle to understand me.

Comment: 1. Do you want US or UK (or some other) pronunciation? 2, What form do you want our answer to take? Phonetic symbols? We cannot speak to you live on this website.

Comment: ***John*** (UK and US) http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/john

Comment: I.P.A. is nothing more than gibberish to most people, including my own foolish self. You might want to try reading it as rhyming with "on" or "lawn", ignoring the subtle, if not silent, H. I think the only other way we can help is to describe the steps of the process one at a time, (possibly connecting those with the I.P.A. symbols). I'd consider doing that but I'm neither a phoneticist, nor am I familiar with the jargon used to describe various parts of the mouth or actions of the throat. I doubt it can be easily cited too.

Comment: Pronounce the "j" the same way you pronounce it in **j**azz*, the "oh" as it is pronounced in *h**o**t*, and then "n" is pretty standard.

Comment: @Tonepoet: Study of phonetics and phonology is unquestionably valuable in answering these questions; the "h" is not only silent or subtle, but actually nonexistent in the spoken form of this word, and it rhymes with "lawn" only for a subset of English speakers (those who pronounce "dawn" and "don" as homophones). As for the jargon, there is some value to it, although it is true that it can be avoided in many cases. But even if most native English speakers are not familiar with the IPA, many speakers of English as a second language have encountered this alphabet in their studies.

Comment: It rhymes with "Han", as in "Han Solo".

Comment: @sumelic That is essentially what I meant by silent. The matter at hand is also bit of a dilemma: If you understand I.P.A. you won't usually need our help with pronunciation anyway, since you could just reference a dictionary, so I assumed Stephan does not. If you do not understand I.P.A., it will not help without some other type of instruction and that's difficult to do in text, which is why I.P.A. exists. However upon reconsideration, the dilemma is a false one in this case, since most dictionaries don't usually include names so maybe providing I.P.A. can help, if Stephan can understand it.

Comment: @HotLicks in Italian the letter J is pronounced similar to Y as in *yacht*, so unless we hear the OP's speech it's impossible to know where he's going "wrong", but John/Jon is such a common name I'm a little surprised the OP needs help on this word. P.S Stephen, my tip about "oh" refers to the sound of O in *hot*, nothing to do with the letter H which is silent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Josh61's comment.

or try Macmillan:

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/american/john

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/john
MacMillan seems to use the same sample as Cambridge for BrE, but a different one for AmE. (But maybe I can't discern slight differences in British pronuciation, as I am an AmE native speaker)

For crowdsourced samples, try
http://forvo.com/word/john/#en

In other words, LMGIFY.